# T9 synonyms in java implementation

Tags: algorithm, trie

I am trying to implement t9 algorithms using Trie. Can someone please suggest how to calculate all the permutations of words(valid or invalid both) for a given numeric input.

For eg in T9 phone: 2 abc, 3 def, 4 ghi......9 wxyz

so if a user presses 234, 3^3 words that can be formed:

adg, aeh, afi, bdg, bei, cfh.....

I am trying to code this in java.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trivial relationship between the solution for a set of n numbers and the solution for the set of n numbers + a new number.

However, I wonder if you really want to enumerate all the words, because the set of words will grow pretty fast: `3^n`

In practice, people use the other way: they have a list of candidate words, and they see which ones are matching a given set of numbers.